# CryptoJS decryption Error: Malformed UTF-8 data

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have a problem with the Crypto-JS libary when trying to decrypt a JSON string.

My encryption/decryption functions:

```
function decrypt(data,key) {
return ((CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data,key)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

}
function encrypt(data,key) {
return (CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key).toString());

}
```

My program works in this order:

```
ArrayWithObjects = [{test:1},{test:2}];
jsonStr = JSON.stringify(ArrayWithObjects);
encryptedString = encrypt(jsonStr,"testkey");
```

Then the encrypted string is uploaded to a file on a webserver. When the user accesses another page php echoes the content of the file (encryped string). I have verified that the string is correct.

```
var encryptedJsonStringFromServer = strFromServer;
var key = document.getElementById("keyInput").value
// Returns error:
decryptedJsonStringFromServer = decrypt(encryptedStringFromServer,key);
```

if i copy the encrypted string from the console, and pass it directly to the decrypt function, the decryption works as intended.

```
console.log(encryptedJsonStringFromServer);
decrypt("stringfromconsole","key") // Works as intented
```